# How to copy rows between a DataGridView bound with a DataTable

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I would like to know how can I copy a row in another DataGridView. They are bound with a datatable. I'm trying this but it don't works!

```
For k As Integer = 0 To gridA.SelectedRows.Count
  Dim row As DataRow = dtA.Rows(gridA.SelectedRows(k).Index)
  dtB.ImportRow(row)
Next
```

Then delete rows from gridA:

```
For k As Integer = 0 To gridA.SelectedRows.Count
  dtA.Rows.RemoveAt(gridA.SelectedRows(k).Index)
Next
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception?

Comment: "If the DataRow that is passed as a parameter is in a detached state, it is ignored, and no exception is thrown." - [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.importrow.aspx). Could that be the case? Are you getting any exceptions or is the table not showing any rows after importing?

Comment: You can't use any sort of index to match row in DataGridView and DataTable because index in your view may not correspond to index in DataTable. The index in your view corresponds to index in the DataView. Even if you didn't defined one, there is default one. So, you need to go after DataView, not DataSource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the index of the data grid can be a problem since the rows might be sorted in a different order than the DataTable.

I re-worked your example to use the actual row objects to move and delete:

```
Dim rows As DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection = gridA.SelectedRows

For Each row As DataGridViewRow In rows
  dtB.ImportRow(DirectCast(row.DataBoundItem, DataRowView).Row)
Next

For Each row As DataGridViewRow In rows
  dtA.Rows.Remove(DirectCast(row.DataBoundItem, DataRowView).Row)
Next
```